# Set icon size globally in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

I have a Windows 10 laptop and I want Explorer to show large icons everywhere. It's not a problem to set icons size in one folder, but can it be done globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a folder and customize the views as you like.

Select the `View` tab and click `Options`

In the Folder Options `View` tab, click `Apply to folders`

Click `Yes` when the following message displays.

```
Do you want all folders of this type to match this folder's view settings?

[Yes] [No]
```

You need to repeat this for each folder type.. Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos.